# Cosmos DB Query Metrics

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I had question regarding QueryMetrics returned by Cosmos DB API.

As per Azure Portal I have 5 partitions in my DB. I am setting `PopulateQuery=true` in `FeedOptions` when querying CosmosDB to confirm and check expensive queries. Because it's a `SELECT *` query I am expecting 5 query metrics returned each per partition with correct partition ids.

I do get 5 different query metrics but each metric has the same partitionId.

Is this is bug or am I doing something wrong. See the example below.

```
DocumentClient documentClient = null;
DocumentCollection collection = null;

FeedOptions feedOptions = new FeedOptions
{
    EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
    PopulateQueryMetrics = true
    MaxItemCount = -1,
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5,
    MaxBufferedItemCount = 100
};

string query = "SELECT * FROM docs
         WHERE docs.Type = @docType AND
            (docs.A - docs.B - (IS_NULL(docs.C)?0:docs.C))
                / (IS_NULL(docs.Info.D)?1:docs.Info.D.E)
                > @threshold"
IDocumentQuery<dynamic> documentQuery = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery(Collection.SelfLink, query, feedOptions).AsDocumentQuery();

while (documentQuery.HasMoreResults)
{
    FeedResponse<dynamic> feedResponse = await documentQuery.ExecuteNextAsync();
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, QueryMetrics> partitionIdToQueryMetrics = feedResponse.QueryMetrics;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, QueryMetrics> kvp in partitionIdToQueryMetrics)
    {
        string partitionId = kvp.Key;
        QueryMetrics queryMetrics = kvp.Value;
        DoSomeLoggingOfQueryMetrics(query, partitionId, queryMetrics);
    }
}
```

Data is partitioned by an ID. That ID is not part of the query.

PartitionID in the above query for all 5 times is 0. But all the other metrics are different.

Shouldn't this be 0, 1, 2 ,3, 4.

Comment: any reason for the java tag?

Comment: @JohnB I was throwing out the question to all the Cosmos DB users across Java and C#. My assumption is symptoms should be same across tech stack. Though if it's against policies I will remove the tag.

Comment: no - all good ..

Comment: I would at least consider the possibility that all your top 5 documents are in a single partition key range id. Round trips don't only happen once per partition key range id. Also it doesn't look like you are running a CrossPartitionQuery from your code so it's expected. Is your collection partitioned? I know you said that you can see 5 partitions on the portal but your code contradicts that statement.

Comment: I didn't want to add the real query in here because it has business attached to it. I changed the above now to simple SELECT * reflecting somewhat real scenario. But yes my data is partitioned by a key which is the reason why I see different partition types in Azure Portal.

Comment: I still can't see whether this is a cross partition query or not. If you modify the way you execute the query in order to ask the question then we can't accurately answer it. Please update the FeedOptions object with the one you actually use. Also let us know if the where clause of your quest includes the partition key definition.

Comment: @NickChapsas added the query as explicit as I could with out explicitly stating each field. Updated FeedOptions as well. Data is partitioned by ID which is not part of the query.